# XSLT: Retrieve element that contains a particular string, or first element if absent

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an **XML list** of "devices".

```
<devices>
  <device>NOKIA-43</device>
  <device>HTC-7</device>
  <device>SAMSUNG-376</device>
<devices>
```

Using **XSLT**, I want to retrieve the **first "HTC*" device** if there is one, or the **first device** if there are no HTC devices.

What XSLT code would do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a very simple, one-liner XPath solution and for the general pattern for solving such problems. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this XPath one-liner**:

```
  /*/device[starts-with(., 'HTC')][1] 
| 
  /*/device[1][not(/*/device[starts-with(., 'HTC')])]
```

**Generally**, **to select node `$n1` when some `$condition` is `true()` and to select node `$n2` when this condition is `false()`:**

```
   $n1[$condition] | $n2[not($condition)]
```

**Explanation**:

The above expression is the union (`|`) of two sub-expressions of which only one selects a node, depending on the value of the specific `$condition`.

**Finally**, in XSLT one will use this XPath expression like this:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "  /*/device[starts-with(., 'HTC')][1] 
    | 
      /*/device[1][not(/*/device[starts-with(., 'HTC')])]
   "/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility (tested with Oxygen/XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="//devices">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="device[starts-with(text(),'HTC')]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="device[starts-with(text(),'HTC')][position()=1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="device[position()=1]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="device">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction! But with this code, if there are several HTC devices, they are all returned, instead of just the first one, right?

Comment: OK, just adding [position()=1] at the end of the first apply-templates apparently did the trick. Could you please update your answer so that I can accept it?